# Vue.js counting json value

Tags: vue.js

I have this Json

```
all_subjects: [
{
id: 1,
subject_code: "COMP101",
description: "Knowledge Work Software & Presentation ",
name: "",
grade: [
{
id: 103,
subject_id: "1",
user_id: "17",
grade: "F",
reviewed: "0"
},
{
id: 104,
subject_id: "1",
user_id: "16",
grade: "F",
reviewed: "0"
}
]
},
```

> my view

```
 <tbody v-for="subject in subjects">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span> @{{ subject.subject_code }}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span> @{{ subject.description }} </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span> @{{ subject.grade.grade->count() }} </span>
          </td>
          <td><span> <div class="btn btn-crimson btn-inline-block"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn-view-more">View more info</a></div> </span></td>
        </tr>       
      </tbody>
```

how do I count the that is F.
I received the json value using vue.resource this.$http.get throught API Call.
I'm trying this @{{ all_subjects.grade.grade->count() }} it doesn't work.
I wanted to count the subjects failure inside the v-for loop in vue.js what are the ways around this?

Comment: From the JSON grade is a string so what do you exactly mean by count the grade. And you should not use PHP's -> operator where you are using it because Blade will not process it as you have ignored it with the @. Guessing you are using Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a method `count()` that doesn't exist in your code. Also, you can't call methods the same way in Javascript as you do in PHP. So you can't use the `->` operator to make a method call.

You can add a new method in your Vue vm:

```
methods: {
        count: function(subject) {
            var grades = subject.grade.filter(function(grade) {
                return grade.grade === 'F';
            });
            return grades.length;
        }
    },
```

The code above works by using Javascript's [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

Then call that method in your view:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="subject in all_subjects">
        Number of F's: {{ count(subject) }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also note that in your `v-for` you are referencing `subjects` instead of `all_subjects`.